# getStaticProps returning empty props in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to `getStaticProps` and Next.js and I have been using `useEffect` to fetch data. Now I am trying to fetch and display data using `getStaticProps`, but I am not able to fetch data. It says props is undefined. What have I done wrong here?

```
function Question(props) {

  return (
    <div className="question11">
      {console.log(props)} // log says undefined
      {Items.map((itm) => (
        <a href={"https://wixten.com/query/" + itm._id} key={itm._id}>
         <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
         </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi`);
  const posts = await res.json();

 console.log("check");// this is diplayed as undefined in cmd
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}
export default Question;
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-kirch-5f71u?file=/src/App.js

I think `export async function getStaticProp` is not working.

I removed the file in pages/question/index.js and when I access now
http://localhost:3000/questions,
I am getting the list displayed. I want this to display in http://localhost:3000/.
When I try this url, I am getting the following error.

http://localhost:3000/questions
[image]

http://localhost:3000/
[image]

I have imported question.js inside the index.js file so it had to work, but I am getting this undefined error.

Here is the index.js file:

```
export default function Home() {

  function clickQuestion() {

  return (
    <>
  
      <Navigation />
     
          <Question />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have added the entire index.js file in CodeSandbox because it's lengthy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wiles-8soq1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i checked everything is right . 
could you try return static data (like string) from `getStaticProps` and catch it in component ?

Comment: @mohamad_sdg can u pls share the code u tried in codesandbox

Comment: @mohamad_sdg i am new to  getStaticProps can u tell me how i can add static data

Comment: here you are https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-xrrpx

Comment: @mohamad_sdg i have updated the question pls do have a look

Comment: For `getStaticProps` to work `Question` has to be used as a page. If you want to import it as a component in another page the data has to be fetched in that component's `getStaticProps` instead.

Comment: so i should fetch  data in index.js?

Comment: Yes, and pass it down to the `Question` component.